# SDFX / Developer Console Delay in Deploying Lightning Component Changes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx

I am using the `sfdx force:source:push` plugin, and editing my components in a `<aura:component>`, that is displayed inside a *Lightning Component Tab*. When I make markup changes to the component in my local file-system and push via the above command OR in the developer console to my scratch org,

I am not seeing the changes reflected until I log out of the org and reload the app?

I am not seeing any errors in the developer console "Problems" tab? Is there some sort of delay in updating lightning components?

I have disabled the cache in chrome developer tools, to no greater effect.

Sometimes they show immediately, otherwise I am not sure if they have unless I change a text string?

Comment: @sfdcfox well that was obvious... and this was at the top of the Trailhead documents and I just didn't read it right?

Comment: In all fairness, I did have to do a bit of research. It's in a developerforce blog post, but I couldn't tell you where it is in the "official" docs.